# User should not be allowed to edit language

Tags: i18n-l10n

I have a question regarding this.
I have a Multilingual site in drupal 8 and i want to disable the edit language for user, so they can´t change the language, if they have chosen one or redirect them, if they are trying.
Of course if you are administrator, you should be able to change their languages and my own.

Any modules, which can do this or configuration somewhere in the i18 module? Or does this require a custom made module?

Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are options under `Configuration » Regional and language » Languages » Detection and selection` where you can set the **User** Detection method to be the first one, or maybe the only one, that determines which language to display the site in.

This way the logged in users would only be able to see the site in the language chosen in their profiles.

To prevent them from changing it try [Language access](https://www.drupal.org/project/language_access).

Comment: Thanks. It helped, so when i have created an account with english i could not go to another language in the URL.